# Maven deploy in github actions keeps failing but runs fine locally

Tags: maven, deployment, github-actions

Hey I've been trying to make my github actions deploy github packages after building and testing my changes but whatever I try I keep getting the following error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ topfind-common ---
[INFO] Uploading to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/topfind/topfindscraper/com/topfind/topfind-common/1.121/topfind-common-1.121.jar
[INFO] Uploading to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/topfind/topfindscraper/com/topfind/topfind-common/1.121/topfind-common-1.121.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  21.077 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-26T14:01:59Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project topfind-common: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.topfind:topfind-common:jar:1.121 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/topfind/topfindscraper) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project topfind-common: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.topfind:topfind-common:jar:1.121 in github
```

The tests pass without problems and I have the following in my workflow file:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 13
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 13
    - name: Get user
      run: echo 'The username is' ${{ github.actor }}
    - name: Build with Maven
      env:
        USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: mvn -B -e deploy --file pom.xml --settings settings.xml
    - uses: actions/delete-package-versions@v1
      with:
        package-name: 'com.topfind.topfind-scraper'
```

My pom file has a distributionManagement that points to the repository. Everything works fine when I do mvn deploy locally and it doesn't ask for anything else. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see your pom file, i'm thinking that the setup needs some slight adjustments. Per your statement that your local build is working properly then my thoughts are to look at your pipeline setup.

Instead of passing password just pass the token. Exact example on how to setup the workflow for publishing can be found here
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/language-and-framework-guides/publishing-java-packages-with-maven

Distribution manager should have the following if not already

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>GitHub Packages</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/topfind/topfindscraper</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

And your workflow steps should be as follows

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 13
  - name: Publish package
    run: mvn -B deploy
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

NOTE: Make sure that your github token as read/write access to packages to make sure the deploy is allowed

**UPDATE 1**

Per request in comments, here is the setup for creating a token for publishing

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Token needs to have access to repo as well if it is a private repo. Otherwise. you just need the permissions below depending if you want your token to allow read, write, or delete when dealing with github packages.

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/publishing-and-managing-packages/about-github-packages

[image]

Comment: Hey Edward. Thank you for the reply. Do you know how I can make sure that the github token has read/write access to the packages?

Comment: updated the response to provide instructions on how to add token

Comment: It keeps saying the following: Transfer failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/topfind/topfindscraper/com/topfind/topfind-common/1.121/topfind-common-1.121.jar 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

Comment: I created the token like you said, following the tutorial and I am passing the token to the org, and using it as a GITHUB_TOKEN but it still doesn't work. Not sure what else I am missing.

Comment: @overflowed I just checked your repo and it appears it is private so you need to add repo scope to make it work. I updated the response above to include the explanation of each permission.